# does google provide techincal support for dataproc's optional components ex. Ranger?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, dataproc, google-cloud-dataproc-serverless, google-cloud-dataproc-metastore

does google provide techincal support for dataproc's optional components ex. Ranger?
if yes, can someone leave a link to verify?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, google provides technical support for dataproc's optional components ex Ranger. You can install the component when you create a Dataproc cluster. Note though that components can be added to clusters created with Dataproc version 1.3 and later and that the Ranger component requires the installation of the Solr component. You can check the full documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/components/ranger)